# How to properly use formatter and editor in Slickgrid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, slickgrid

We are using slickgrid in our angular directive. 
And we would like to use another list directive (simple select element with input) in a cell/column of Slickgrid.

I want the list element to be visible when the grid is available, so user knows there is a list. Therefor I am using the list directive as formatter. It **Is** visible when the grid is rendered.

### The Problem:

When the cell that holds list element is clicked, the editor mode is never fired because of the list element click event.

We thought to use an image of list that user knows there is a list, and when clicked open the list.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Mind sharing a sample [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about your setup?

Comment: We have managed to get it work using our list directive as readonly. I will add my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have managed to get it done using list directive as our rendere/formatter as well as editor.

We made our list directive as ReadOnly so it does not fire click event. And now one sees a list element when grid is rendered. And when one clicks on the cell with list, the list is automatically opened via code. The only problem we have now with this solution is that how to copy selected Item from editor to formatter (if anyone knows, please share).

Any better solution is also welcomed.