# How to show data from cell in formatter of the same cell in slickgrid

Tags: angularjs-directive, slickgrid

For user friendliness, I have used a list (simple angularjs directive with input and select) in a column of slickgrid. So user knows that there is a list. 
(Solved from my previous question: [Using formatter and editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358532/how-to-properly-use-formatter-and-editor-in-slickgrid))

As an editor I have used the same list. It is working now, the only problem is when the cell is edited (an item from the list is selected), the cell gets the item, but it is not visible, since the formatter is above it.

Note: We are using grid as a angular directive.
Now the question is, is it possible to show the value of cell in formatter too?

**EDIT:** It is how I am using list directive:

```
var _preCompiledComboList = $compile('<dcs-combo-list data-enabled="true" readonly data-selected-item="value"></dcs-combo-list>')(newScope);
```

Later it is used as:

```
var _cellComboListRenderer = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){
    return _center(_preCompiledComboList[0].outerHTML);
};
```

The value in in renderer function is the cell value. And how can I set **data-selected-item** attribute of list directive to be the value?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. But I am not happy with the solution.

Right before returning my compiled directive, I am searching the first input element, and setting the value of it to be the "value" of the cell.

```
 var _cellComboListRenderer = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){
     _preCompiledComboList[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute("value", value);
     return _center(_preCompiledComboList[0].outerHTML);
 };
```

I want more elegant solution, for instance directive scope.